# How to merge two polygon features using topojson merge

Tags: javascript, geojson, topojson

I am trying to use topojson to merge two polygon features together.  The two polygons at first do not contain similar/shared points which I believe topojson.merge needs in order to perform a merge.  Prior to performing the topology I run through the polygons and add the shared points to the polygon that needs them.  The resulting FeatureCollection, "collection",  created is as follows:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties":
        {
            "id": "area_1"
        },
        "geometry":
        {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [148, 105],
                    [160, 105],
                    [160, 113],
                    [148, 113]
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties":
        {
            "id": "area_2"
        },
        "geometry":
        {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [143, 113],
                    [148, 113],
                    [160, 113],
                    [171, 113],
                    [171, 132],
                    [143, 132]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

`let topology = topojson.topology({ collection: collection });`

The resulting topology is:

```
{
    "type": "Topology",
    "objects":
    {
        "collection":
        {
            "type": "GeometryCollection",
            "geometries": [
            {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "arcs": [
                    [-1]
                ],
                "properties":
                {
                    "id": "area_1"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "arcs": [
                    [-2]
                ],
                "properties":
                {
                    "id": "area_2"
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "arcs": [
        [
            [
                [148, 105],
                [160, 105],
                [160, 113],
                [148, 113]
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                [143, 113],
                [148, 113],
                [160, 113],
                [171, 113],
                [171, 132],
                [143, 132]
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

Here is how I am calling the merge:
`topojson.merge(topology, topology.objects.collection.geometries);`

and the resulting error is:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined - stitch.js:13`

lines of code where error occurs:

```
arcs.forEach(function (i, j) {
    var arc = topology.arcs[i < 0 ? ~i : i],
        t;

    if (arc.length < 3 && !arc[1][0] && !arc[1][1]) {
      t = arcs[++emptyIndex], arcs[emptyIndex] = i, arcs[j] = t;
    }
  });
```

It seems like the error occurs because the code is looking for arcs one step further down than they exists...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

With `v3.1.0`, it's working for me.

```js
topojson.merge(topology, topology.objects.collection.geometries)
```

See [the tests](https://github.com/topojson/topojson-client/blob/71e5bd6428fd8b7a40fa980d2ef7862140851f03/test/merge-test.js#L10) for examples of calling `topojson.merge()`.

### With the data from the OP

```js
const collection = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "area_1"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [148, 105],
            [160, 105],
            [160, 113],
            [148, 113]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "area_2"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [143, 113],
            [148, 113],
            [160, 113],
            [171, 113],
            [171, 132],
            [143, 132]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};

const topology = topojson.topology({
  collection
});

const merged = topojson.merge(topology, topology.objects.collection.geometries);

console.log(merged);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson-server@3.0.1/dist/topojson-server.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson-client@3.1.0/dist/topojson-client.min.js"></script>
```